# javascript ussing ssh to run server program

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Project: creating a webpage to connect to a server and execute any command or program and retrieve the output to the client web page.

I have developed same functionality unsing Socket_io and node.js..
But every time I have to run first "node file.js" in client cmd and the open the webpage to execute the program from sever.

I there any simple JavaScript which automatically run automatically web opening a webpage and connect to the server using ssh and retrieve the output of and executable file instead of running some extra files on cmd ,etc.

Comment: if I'm not mistaken, running plain JS from a regular webpage is bound to some serious security rule. So connecting to a server and executing files + retrieving the ouput after the execution with ONLY js seems unlikely.. Perhaps issueing a GET call to a webservice and retrieving the response or like you said with something like node.js but otherwise...

Answer (score 0):

You have to be running a server for your javascript to connect to. To be clear: JavaScript in a browser can only connect a webserver, not any arbitrary service on any random server. Instead, if you wanted to implement SSH in a browser, you would have to write a server to act as a proxy between the webpage and the target server.

[Using Javascript to connect with server using protocol other than HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799005/using-javascript-to-connect-with-server-using-protocol-other-than-http)